# how to use vaadin icon as img src?

Tags: html, image, vaadin

I have an `image tag` in my code and I want to use the `Vaadin icon` such as `lumo:undo` as an `img src`.

I use `Vaadin 23` with `lit Element` and I have access to the backend classes.

**Does anyone know how to realize this?**

```
<img id="contact" src="${this.setVaadinIconAsImage()}" />


setVaadinIconAsImage(){
    /*  Create path to the Vaadin icon. I can even call the backend class to retrieve a vaadin-icon .svg path here. */  
    
    /* let contact = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#contact");
           contact.setAttribute("src", "lumo:undo"); 
    */      
    
    return "lumo:undo";     
}
```

Comment: That's not possible. Why don't you use the vaadin-icon component?

Comment: The reason why I don't use Vaadin-icon is that I'm not allowed to change the `<img /`tag.
I'm only allowed to add `onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='${this.altImageOnError(item.id)}';"` event to it.

Answer (score 1):

Lumo icons are distributed as an icon font, and you can’t use font characters as an image source.

The source SVG files are here: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/tree/main/packages/vaadin-lumo-styles/icons/svg

You can copy those to your project, and then reference them in the `src` attribute.